# How do I set the HttpRequestHeader for a HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to set the HttpRequestHeader for a HttpWebRequest like so:

```
new HttpWebRequest().Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/4.0");
```

But I get an exception: `System.ArgumentException: This header must be modified using the appropriate property`.

How should I be setting the header?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`UserAgent`is a property. So set it like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = new HttpWebRequest();
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0";
```

Comment: As the standard constructor is obsolet, try HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUrl);

Comment: @Emixam23 have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contentlength(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I finaly found another solution, ContentLenght doesn't works for HttpWebReuqest Xamarin, there is the solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37837204/xamarin-forms-cannot-set-the-contentlenght-of-httpwebrequest?noredirect=1#comment63172228_37837204

Comment: how can you set the -u "--user" property in the same way as the UserAgent property?