# Xamarin Forms - Cannot set the ContentLenght of HttpWebRequest

Tags: http-post, xamarin.forms, system.net.httpwebrequest, http-content-length

I tried to mke a request with GET and parameters. However, I got an exception for the WinPhone8.1 which meaned that GET was a violation protocol due to a content added in. So making a POST request is the solution.

Despite my searches, I'm still not able to set the content lenght property of my HttpWebRequest.. Why?

```
private static async void AsyncRequest(string url, string contentType, string methodType, int contentLenght, Action<Object, string> callback, Action<HttpStatusCode, JObject, Action<Object, string>> parserFunction)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.ContentType = contentType;
        request.Method = methodType;
        request.Proxy = null;

        if (methodType == Method.POST)
        {
            request.ContentLenght = "contentLenght";
            request.Headers["content-length"] = "contentLenght";
            request.Headers["Content-Length"] = "contentLenght";
            request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = "contentLenght";
            request.Headers["HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength"] = "contentLenght";
            request.Content.Headers.ContentLength = "contentLenght";

            ...........

            Nothing works ><
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("1");
        Task<WebResponse> task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(
            request.BeginGetResponse,
            asyncResult => request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult),
            (object)null);
        Debug.WriteLine("2");

        await task.ContinueWith(t => ReadStreamFromResponse(t.Result, callback, parserFunction));
    }
```

Comment: what is `"contentLenght"`? Should it not be a long value instead of string?    @Emixam23

Comment: Because VS2015 says: " Cannot implicity convert type 'int' to 'string' "

Comment: Add a numeric value as "1000" in string format.

Comment: request.Headers["Content-Length"] = "1000";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to **jsonmcgraw** for its answer on [Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22732/3-pcl-rest-functions-post-get-multipart)

If you want to make a POST request intead of GET request, then there is the two methods which can make you able to make GET/POST requests.

So, first, an async GET request.

```
public static async Task<string> MakeGetRequest(string url, string cookie)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (url);
    request.ContentType = "text/html";
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Headers ["Cookie"] = cookie;

    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync ();
    var respStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    respStream.Flush ();

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (respStream)) {
            //Need to return this response 
        string strContent = sr.ReadToEnd ();
        respStream = null;
            return strContent;
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
public static async Task<MyModel[]> GetInfoAsync(int page, string searchString, string cookie)
{
    string url = Constants.url + Constants.Path+ 
        "page=" + page + 
        "&searchString=" + searchString;

    string result = await WebControl.MakeGetRequest (url, cookie);

    MyModel[] models = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel[]> (result);

    return models;
}
```

Next, an async POST request

```
public static async Task<string> MakePostRequest (string url, string data, string cookie, bool isJson = true)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (url);
    if (isJson)
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
    else 
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Headers ["Cookie"] = cookie;
    var stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync ();
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter (stream)) {
        writer.Write (data);
        writer.Flush ();
        writer.Dispose ();
    }

    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync ();
    var respStream = response.GetResponseStream();


    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (respStream)) {
        //Need to return this response 
        return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
public static async Task<ResultModel> PostInfoAsync(int id, string cookie)
{

    string data = "id=" + id;
    //third param means that the content type is not json
    string resp = await WebControl.MakePostRequest (Constants.url + Constants.Path, data, cookie, false);
    ResultModel model;

    try {
        model =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultModel> (resp);
    }
    catch (Exception) {
        model = new ResultModel{ isSuccess = false, Message = resp };
    }

    return model;
}
```